# $order()->getSubtotal() > "Fatal error: Function name must be a string" on success checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

Im currently inserting google adwords tracking script on my success.phtml and trying to get the total amount from the last order.

Im trying with the following but getting an error:

```
<?php
    $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $total = (float)number_format($order()->getSubtotal(),2);
?>
```

This triggers the following error:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string
```

The line error reference points to: `$total = (float)number_format($order()->getSubtotal(),2);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one instead.

```
<?php
    $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
    $total = (float)number_format($order->getSubtotal(),2);
?>
```

Comment: Perfect - works like a charm - thanks for contributing!